# Arduino ultrasonic sensor weird output

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, hc-sr04

So I just got into arduino and bought Elegoo's car robot v3 kit and built it, but when I put the robot on "object avoidance" it constantly spins as though there is an object in front of it. I tried changing the code and had no luck so I thought maybe it was the sensor itself, when I hooked it up and ran:

```
void loop() {
   a=sr04.Distance();
   Serial.print(a);
   Serial.println("cm");
   delay(1000);
}
```

it displayed the correct distances so I figured it could not be the sensor. The curious thing happened when I added a few lines to the car's code to also make it print the distance it was seeing, and when the sensor is hooked up to the car for whatever reason all it sees is 18cm no matter the actual distance, which explains why it is constantly spinning. I have found the problem, but now my issue is that for the life of me I cannot figure out why it detects only 18cm constantly when hooked to the car.

```
#include <SR04.h>

/*
 * @Description: Rocker_Control
 * @Author: HOU Changhua
 * @Date: 2019-08-12 18:00:25
 * @LastEditTime: 2019-08-27 10:45:29
 * @LastEditors: Please set LastEditors
 */
#include <Servo.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HardwareSerial.h"
#include "ArduinoJson-v6.11.1.h" //ArduinoJson

/*Driving Interface for Ultrasound Ranging*/
#define ECHO_PIN A4
#define TRIG_PIN A5

/*Motor Drive Interface*/
#define ENA 5
#define ENB 6
#define IN1 7
#define IN2 8
#define IN3 9
#define IN4 11

/*Driving Interface for Infrared Pipeline Patrol*/
#define LineTeacking_Pin_Right 10
#define LineTeacking_Pin_Middle 4
#define LineTeacking_Pin_Left 2
#define LineTeacking_Read_Right !digitalRead(10)
#define LineTeacking_Read_Middle !digitalRead(4)
#define LineTeacking_Read_Left !digitalRead(2)

#define carSpeed 180 //PWM(That is: motor speed/vehicle speed)

Servo servo;
unsigned long IR_PreMillis;
unsigned long LT_PreMillis;

enum FUNCTIONMODE
{
  IDLE,
  LineTeacking,
  ObstaclesAvoidance,
  Bluetooth,

} func_mode = IDLE; /*Functional model*/

enum MOTIONMODE
{
  STOP,
  FORWARD,
  BACK,
  LEFT,
  RIGHT
} mov_mode = STOP; /*Motion model*/

void delays(unsigned long t)
{

  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < t; i++)
  {
    getBTData_Plus();
    delay(1);
  }
}

/*Acquisition Distance: Ultrasound*/
unsigned int getDistance(void)
{
  static unsigned int tempda = 0;
  unsigned int tempda_x = 0;
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);
  tempda_x = ((unsigned int)pulseIn(ECHO_PIN, HIGH) / 58);
  if (tempda_x < 150)
  {
    tempda = tempda_x;
  }
  else
  {
    tempda = 30;
  }
  return tempda;
}
/*Control motor: */
void forward(bool debug, int16_t in_carSpeed)
{

  analogWrite(ENA, in_carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, in_carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
  if (debug)
    Serial.println("Go forward!");
}

/*Control motor: */
void back(bool debug, int16_t in_carSpeed)
{

  analogWrite(ENA, in_carSpeed);
  analogWrite(ENB, in_carSpeed);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
  if (debug)
    Serial.println("Go back!");
}
/*Control motor:*/
void left(bool debug, int16_t in_carSpeed)
{
  analogWrite(ENA, 250);
  analogWrite(ENB, 250);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
  if (debug)
    Serial.println("Go left!");
}
/*Control motor:*/
void right(bool debug, int16_t in_carSpeed)
{
  analogWrite(ENA, 250);
  analogWrite(ENB, 250);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
  if (debug)
    Serial.println("Go right!");
}
/*Control motor:*/
void stop(bool debug = false)
{
  digitalWrite(ENA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ENB, LOW);
  if (debug)
    Serial.println("Stop!");
}
/*
  Bluetooth serial port data acquisition and control command parsing
*/
void getBTData_Plus(void)
{
  String comdata = "";

  while ((Serial.available() > 0) && (false == comdata.endsWith("}")))
  {
    comdata += char(Serial.read());
    delay(3);
  }
  if ((comdata.length() > 0) && (comdata != "") && (true == comdata.endsWith("}")))
  {
    StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;                                //Create a JsonDocument object
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, comdata); //Deserialize JSON data
    if (!error)                                                 //Check if deserialization is successful
    {
      int control_mode_N = doc["N"];
      char buf[3];
      uint8_t temp = doc["H"];
      sprintf(buf, "%d", temp);
      String CommandSerialNumber = buf; //Get the serial number of the new command

      switch (control_mode_N)
      {
      case 5: /*Clear mode  processing <command：N 5>*/
        func_mode = Bluetooth;
        mov_mode = STOP;
        Serial.print('{' + CommandSerialNumber + "_ok}");
        break;
      case 3:               /*Remote switching mode  processing <command：N 3>*/
        if (1 == doc["D1"]) // Line Teacking Mode
        {
          func_mode = LineTeacking;
          Serial.print('{' + CommandSerialNumber + "_ok}");
        }
        else if (2 == doc["D1"]) //Obstacles Avoidance Mode
        {
          func_mode = ObstaclesAvoidance;
          Serial.print('{' + CommandSerialNumber + "_ok}");
        }
        break;
      case 2: /*Remote switching mode  processing <command：N 2>*/

        if (1 == doc["D1"])
        {
          func_mode = Bluetooth;
          mov_mode = LEFT;
          Serial.print('{' + CommandSerialNumber + "_ok}");
        }
        else if (2 == doc["D1"])
        {
          func_mode = Bluetooth;
          mov_mode = RIGHT;
          Serial.print('{' + CommandSerialNumber + "_ok}");
        }
        else if (3 == doc["D1"])
        {
          func_mode = Bluetooth;
          mov_mode = FORWARD;
          Serial.print('{' + CommandSerialNumber + "_ok}");
        }
        else if (4 == doc["D1"])
        {
          func_mode = Bluetooth;
          mov_mode = BACK;
          Serial.print('{' + CommandSerialNumber + "_ok}");
        }
        else if (5 == doc["D1"])
        {
          func_mode = Bluetooth;
          mov_mode = STOP;
          Serial.print('{' + CommandSerialNumber + "_ok}");
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

/*Bluetooth remote control mode*/
void bluetooth_mode()
{
  if (func_mode == Bluetooth)
  {
    switch (mov_mode)
    {
    case FORWARD:
      forward(false, carSpeed);
      break;
    case BACK:
      back(false, carSpeed);
      break;
    case LEFT:
      left(false, carSpeed);
      break;
    case RIGHT:
      right(false, carSpeed);
      break;
    case STOP:
      stop();
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
}
/*
  Line Teacking Mode
*/
void line_teacking_mode(void)
{
  if (func_mode == LineTeacking)
  {
    if (LineTeacking_Read_Middle)
    {                           //Detecting in the middle infrared tube
      forward(false, carSpeed); //Control motor：the car moving forward
      LT_PreMillis = millis();
    }
    else if (LineTeacking_Read_Right)
    {                         //Detecting in the right infrared tube
      right(false, carSpeed); //Control motor：the car moving right
      while (LineTeacking_Read_Right)
      {
        getBTData_Plus(); //Bluetooth data acquisition
      }
      LT_PreMillis = millis();
    }
    else if (LineTeacking_Read_Left)
    {                        //Detecting in the left infrared tube
      left(false, carSpeed); //Control motor：the car moving left
      while (LineTeacking_Read_Left)
      {
        getBTData_Plus(); //Bluetooth data acquisition
      }
      LT_PreMillis = millis();
    }
    else
    {
      if (millis() - LT_PreMillis > 150)
      {
        stop(); //Stop motor control：Turn off motor drive mode
      }
    }
  }
}
/*f(x) int */
static boolean function_xxx(long xd, long sd, long ed) //f(x)
{
  if (sd <= xd && xd <= ed)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
/*Obstacle avoidance*/
void obstacles_avoidance_mode(void)
{
  static uint16_t ULTRASONIC_Get = 0;
  static unsigned long ULTRASONIC_time = 0;
  static boolean stateCar = false;
  static boolean CarED = false;
  static uint8_t switc_ctrl = 0x00;
  static boolean timestamp = true;
   Serial.print(A4);
   Serial.println("cm");
   delay(1000);

  if (func_mode == ObstaclesAvoidance)
  {
    servo.attach(3);
    if (millis() - ULTRASONIC_time > 100)
    {
      ULTRASONIC_Get = getDistance(); //Measuring obstacle distance
      ULTRASONIC_time = millis();
      if (function_xxx(ULTRASONIC_Get, 0, 30)) //If the distance is less than Xcm obstacles
      {
        stateCar = true;
        stop(); //stop
      }
      else
      {
        stateCar = false;
      }
    }
    if (false == CarED)
    {
      if (stateCar == true)
      {
        timestamp = true;
        CarED = true;
        switc_ctrl = 0x00;
        stop();          //stop
        servo.write(30); //sets the servo position according to the  value
        delays(500);
        if (function_xxx(getDistance(), 0, 25)) //How many cm in the front have obstacles?
        {
          switc_ctrl |= 0x01;
          //goto
        }
        else
        {
          switc_ctrl &= (~0x01);
        }
        servo.write(150); //sets the servo position according to the  value
        delays(500);
        if (function_xxx(getDistance(), 0, 25)) //How many cm in the front have obstacles?
        {
          switc_ctrl |= 0x02;
          //goto
        }
        else
        {
          switc_ctrl &= (~0x02);
        }
        servo.write(90); //tell servo to go to position in variable 30
        delays(500);
        if (function_xxx(getDistance(), 0, 25)) //How many cm in the front have obstacles?
        {
          switc_ctrl |= 0x04;
          //goto
        }
        else
        {
          switc_ctrl &= (~0x04);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        forward(false, 180); //Control motor：the car moving forwar
        CarED = false;
      }
    }

    if (true == CarED)
    {
      // Get cpu time
      static unsigned long MotorRL_time;
      if (timestamp == true || millis() - MotorRL_time > 420)
      {
        timestamp = false;
        MotorRL_time = millis();
      }
      if (function_xxx((millis() - MotorRL_time), 0, 400))
      {
        switch (switc_ctrl)
        {
        case 0 ... 1:
          left(false, 150); //Control motor：The car moves forward and left
          break;
        case 2:
          right(false, 150); //Control motor：The car moves forward and right
          break;
        case 3:
          forward(false, 150); //Control motor：the car moving forwar
          break;
        case 4 ... 5:
          left(false, 150); //Control motor：The car moves forward and left
          break;
        case 6:
          right(false, 100); //Control motor：The car moves forward and right
          break;
        case 7:
          back(false, 150); //Control motor：Car backwards
          break;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        CarED = false;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    servo.detach();
    ULTRASONIC_Get = 0;
    ULTRASONIC_time = 0;
  }
}
void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);         //initialization
  servo.attach(3, 500, 2400); //500: 0 degree  2400: 180 degree
  servo.write(90);            //sets the servo position according to the 90（middle）

  pinMode(ECHO_PIN, INPUT); //Ultrasonic module initialization
  pinMode(TRIG_PIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT); //Motor-driven port configuration
  pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ENB, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(LineTeacking_Pin_Right, INPUT); //Infrared tracking module port configuration
  pinMode(LineTeacking_Pin_Middle, INPUT);
  pinMode(LineTeacking_Pin_Left, INPUT);
}

void loop(void)
{
  getBTData_Plus();           //Bluetooth data acquisition
  bluetooth_mode();           //Bluetooth remote mode
  line_teacking_mode();       //Line Teacking Mode
  obstacles_avoidance_mode(); //Obstacles Avoidance Mode
}
```

New Debug:

```
/*Acquisition Distance: Ultrasound*/
unsigned int getDistance(void)
{
  static unsigned int tempda = 0;
  unsigned int tempda_x = 0;
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);
  tempda_x = ((unsigned int)pulseIn(ECHO_PIN, HIGH) / 58);
  if (tempda_x < 150)
  {
    tempda = tempda_x;
  }
  else
  {
    tempda = 30;
  }
  Serial.print(tempda);
  Serial.println("cm");
  delay(1000);
  return tempda;
}
```

Comment: You already figured out, that is is not a hardware problem, but a software problem. But you didn't show us your code. We cannot magically see it. Please edit your question to include the actual problematic code (a complete working example please).

Comment: I am trying to post the code, but when I copy paste it, the format gets ruined and I am having trouble getting it to stay in a block.

Comment: Past the code in.  Then highlight the code and click on the stackexchange.com icon for code.   (Oh, I see you have been able to embed code into your question, good.)  BTW, guessing, you are probably having a power supply / battery problem.  What are you using?  And if more than one type of power source, then when are you using them?

Comment: The power source is a 7.4V Lithium Battery 4000mAh.

Comment: I also finally managed to get the code formatted, thank you!

Comment: upvote for caring about the program listing readability without being asked

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Arduino programming and robotics!

As you have discovered, sometimes the magic doesn't work with the first incantation, so some work is required to get the spell just right ;-).

When troubleshooting a problem with a sophisticated system like the Elegoo kit you have, it helps to drastically simplify things to start with to establish a working baseline, then add complexity incrementally until the problem behavior occurs. Then you can concentrate on the (hopefully) smaller piece of code that caused the problem, without having to wade through lines and lines of irrelevant programming.

It appears that you have started in the right direction with your simple program to display the distance once per second, so you have the right idea.  If you haven't done so already, I suggest you create a completely new Arduino sketch, with just your once/second measurement as the entire program (plus the #include  necessary to access the sensor).  Once you have it running in isolation, then add just the 'obstacles_avoidance_mode(void)' function along with some print statements to instrument the different decision trees of the function.  For instance, I might simplify the function down to something like this:

```
void obstacles_avoidance_mode(void)
{
  static uint16_t ULTRASONIC_Get = 0;
  static unsigned long ULTRASONIC_time = 0;
  ULTRASONIC_Get = getDistance(); //Measuring obstacle distance
  ULTRASONIC_time = millis();
  Serial.print("time = ");Serial.print(ULTRASONIC_time);
  Serial.print(", dist = ");Serial.println(ULTRASONIC_Get);
 }
```

Then add the required 'getDistance() function to the bottom of your new test program and call 'obstacles_avoidance_mode(void)' once per second.  Once you have that working to your satisfaction, then start adding small pieces of 'obstacles_avoidance_mode(void)' one at a time, along with whatever preconditions are required to force each small section to execute as you cause the sensor's reported distance to change by moving your hand toward and away from the sensor. Don't worry about the motors and/or servos all; you can hook them up later as needed.

By doing this you should very rapidly come to understand how the program is making decisions, without getting bogged down in all the other stuff going on in the full robot code.

Hope this helps,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

`Serial.print(A4)` makes no sense, that just directly reads the GPIO pin (0 or 1). Maybe that statement is actually messing up the configuration of the GPIO and messing up the distance measurement.
You need to use the `getDistance()` function. For debugging, try printing the tempda return value just before the return statement. You still might need to convert that echo timing to cm distance though.

Comment: I removed the Serial.print string and added the debugging code, but as I am very new to this I believe I messed something up as it no longer shows me the distance in the serial monitor.

Comment: I placed the new debug up above as I can't get it to format well in comment form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ultrasonic sensor to get the water level in a watertank for my irrigation system. The following piece of code for measuring the distance works fine for me. I'd suggest to replace:

```
tempda_x = ((unsigned int)pulseIn(ECHO_PIN, HIGH) / 58);
```

(BTW what is 58?)
 with the following:

```
long duration;
duration = pulseIn(ECHO_PIN, HIGH);
tempda_x = duration*0.034029/2;
```

0.034029 is the speed of sound per second(m/s). And this times the duration it takes sound to get back, divided by 2 gives us the distance from the object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not too sure as to what 58 is as this is mainly code from the Elegoo robot car v3. However when I replace that line with yours it tells me "duration was not declared in this scope"

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I forgot to mention to declare duration at the top of your script as 
long duration;
or just in getDistance function ...